# Unboundedness of commutator of unbounded self-adjoint positive operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I wanna see a pair of two unbounded positive and self-adjoint operators $A$ and $B$ (if one operator is bounded is even better) such that $AB-BA$ is unbounded. I guess
 if $A$ is a second order differential operator on some appropriate domain and $B$ is a multiplication operator, then this is perhaps enough. I would like you to confirm this and why not give a better visualised example.

Thanks and I hope you'll be great as usual.

Math.

Comment: Yes, what you thought is enough. Let $A$ be a multiplication operator by a bounded function with unbounded derivative, and let $B$ be the derivative. Here all operators are on (a dense subspace of) $L^2(0, 1)$.